# Obtaining the Fundamental Solution of $1-\partial_x^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function, fundamental-solution

How does one obtain the fundamental solution of the differential operator $(1-\partial_x^2)$? There does not seem to be any easily accesible literature specifically describing how this is done, except in the case of very simple or highly specific differential operators.

The attempted solution is as follows:
\begin{align}
&(1-\partial_x^2)G(x) = \delta(x)\\
\Rightarrow &G(x)-G''(x) = \delta(x)\\
\Rightarrow &\mathcal{L}\{G\}-\mathcal{L}\{G''\} = 1\\
\Rightarrow &\mathcal{L}\{G\} - s^2\mathcal{L}\{G\}+sG(0)+G'(0)=1\\
\Rightarrow &(1-s^2)\mathcal{L}\{G\} = 1-sG(0)-G'(0)\\
\Rightarrow &\mathcal{L}\{G\} = \frac{1-G'(0)}{1-s^2} - G(0)\frac{s}{1-s^2}\\
\Rightarrow &\mathcal{L}\{G\} = \frac{1-G'(0)}{1-s^2} + G(0)\frac{s}{s^2-1}\\
\end{align}
Then apply the inverse Laplace transform to get
$$ G(x) = \frac{1-G'(0)}{2}e^{-|x|} + G(0)\cosh(x) $$
We now attempt to determine the value of $G(0)$ and $G'(0)$:
$$ G(0) = \frac{1-G'(0)}{2} + G(0) $$
Therefore, $G'(0)=1$. However, this then means that $G(x)=G(0)\cosh(x)$, which implies that $G'(x)=G(0)\sinh(x)$, which gives that $G'(0)=0$, so we end up getting $0=1$. Something, clearly, must be wrong.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: One approach: Solve the ODE for $x<0$ and $x>0$ respectively and then match the solutions at $x=0$ by matching the function value and you get a second condition by integrating the ODE from $x=0-\epsilon$ to $x=0+\epsilon$ and taking $\epsilon\to 0$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, since I'm not terribly familiar with this as a subject?

Comment: For $x<0$ the ODE is $G''(x) = G(x)$. You can solve this (in terms of two free constants). Same for $x>0$ (same ODE and two new constants). The relationships between the constants is found by matching at $x=0$. Because of the delta-function the derivative will have a jump at $x=0$.

Comment: When integrating the ODE from $-\epsilon$ to $\epsilon$, which equation (i.e. which set of constants) should be used?

Comment: Did you mean $f(\epsilon)-f(-\epsilon) = 1$?

Comment: By solving $G''(x)=G(x)$ we get $G(x)=C_1e^x+C_2e^{-x}$ for $x>0$, and the same but with $C_3$ and $C_4$ instead of $C_1,C_2$ for $x<0$. Setting these equal at $x=0$ means $C_1+C_2=C_3+C_4$, which makes sense. Integrating the expression, however, gives $0=1$, since $\int G(x)dx = G'(x)$, so this doesn't seem to work, at least to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding you. By integrating the ODE, you mean the following, I hope:
$\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}G(x)-G''(x)dx = \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\delta(x)dx = 1$. This gives $[C_1e^x-C_2e^{-x} - C_1e^{x}+C_2e^{-x}]_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon = 1$, but the left-hand-side is $0$ (since everything cancels) and the right-hand-side is 1, so we end up with $0=1$. Of course, the constants are only $C_1$ and $C_2$ on one side, but it still cancels if you write everything out.

Comment: Here is a different way of writing the calulation I'm doing, which I hope you can point out the error in:
$\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}G(x)-G''(x)dx = \int_{-\epsilon}^0G(x)-G''(x)dx + \int_0^{\epsilon}G(x)-G''(x)dx$. But we know that $G(x)-G''(x)=0$, since $G$ is the solution to $G(x)=G''(x)$. Hence both integrals go away over their respective intervals of integration.

Comment: Am I correct in interpreting what you are doing as writing $\int G(x)-G''(x)dx = \int G(x)dx - \int G''(x)dx$, and then the left integral somehow goes away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the objective is to find the fundamental solution of $1−\partial^2_x$, we can approach this similarly to how you began by solving the corresponding differential equation, which we will do via Fourier transforms.
\begin{align}
& \\(1−\partial^2_x )G(x) = \delta(x)
& \\\Rightarrow G(x)-G''(x) = \delta(x)
& \\\Rightarrow \mathcal{F}(G(x))-\mathcal{F}(G''(x)) = \mathcal{F}(\delta(x))
& \\\Rightarrow \mathcal{F}(G(x)) - (2\pi i \epsilon)^2\mathcal{F}(G(x)) = 1
& \\\Rightarrow (1 + 4\pi^2 \epsilon^2)\mathcal{F}(G(x)) = 1
& \\\Rightarrow \mathcal{F}(G(x)) = \frac{1}{(1 + 4\pi^2 \epsilon^2)}
& \\\Rightarrow \mathcal{F^{-1}}\mathcal{F}(G(x)) = \mathcal{F^{-1}}\frac{1}{(1 + 4\pi^2 \epsilon^2)}
& \\\Rightarrow G(x) = \frac{e^{-|x|}}{2}
\end{align}
This should be the solution Fundamental solution of the Differential operator

Comment: Note that $f(x)=e^x$ and $f(x)=e^{-x}$ both solve the equation $(1-\partial_x^2)f(x)=0$, so any linear combination of these functions can be added to your solution and you will still have a fundamental solution.